# Fargate Java microservices experiencing java.net.SocketException: Connection reset errors

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-fargate

We are seeing intermittent Connection reset exceptions when **service A** tries to talk to **service B** over its ALB.

This is particularly noticeable when there's been a period of no requests to service B for a prolonged period of time, say an hour/2 hours. Once Service A starts making requests to Service B, the first couple will throw that exception but all subsequent will succeed.

Service A and B are both Spring boot services running their default HTTP client and tomcat server configs. We've fiddled with various parameters (ex: Connection/Request Timeout etc.) with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like the images are spinning down, when idle, are you sure images are always up?

Comment: Did you manage to find the problem for this? I'm having this exact same problem right now